# Catch event when a JTabbedPane tab is clicked (before actual state change)

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I know I can add a `ChangeListener` to detect when the tab changed, but I would like to do it before it changed. Here's my situation:

when my user tries to switch tab I do a validation some content on the current tab and the tab should switch only if the validation passes. If I use `addChangeListener` and switch it back upon validation failure (hoping that it happens fast enough that I won't see it) I will see the tab switched and then immediately switched back which looks stupid.

Something within `JTabbedPane` is responding to tab click for sure that triggers a state change, I just wonder if this functionality is exposed outside of the class. Either way, is there a good solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice approach to do validation before switching tabs by creating a custom VetoableSingleSelectionModel:

[Forbid tab change in a JTabbedPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389801/forbid-tab-change-in-a-jtabbedpane)

Comment: Overriding `setSelectedIndex()` works. Thanks Freek. (Should've thought of this :) )

Comment: @user1861088 spend tons of time but you suggestion really works .. thanks